# MEMBER OF in EJB-QL 3 doesn't work

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, jpql

I would like to retrieve many 'Access' which have one 'Role' in common.

It's the named query:

```
SELECT access 
FROM Access AS access 
WHERE :role MEMBER OF access.listRole
```

The **Access** entity

```
public class Access implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String libelle;

    @ManyToOne
    private Module oneModule;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Role> listRole;
    /* Setter & Getter */
}
```

The **Role** entity

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Flag oneFlag;
    @Transient
    private int lengthAccess;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="oneRole")
    private List<UserAccount> listUserAccount;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Access> listAccess;

    /* Geter & Setter */
}
```

But I don't achieve to do the right EJB-QL !

**Configuration:**

- EJB 3
- MySQL (InnoDB)
- jBoss
- Plop

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My link @ManyToMany between my two classes isn't write in the right way, during the project's building, 2 Tables has created in MySQL ("access_role" for my link @ManyToMany in the 'access' class, and role_access for my link @ManyToMany in the 'role' class)

So, to correct this, I modified like this

```
public class Access implements Serializable {
    // ...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listAccess")
    private List<Role> listRole;
   // ...
}

public class Role implements Serializable {
    // ...
    @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "access_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "access_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Access> listAccess;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem. When running the JPQL query you provided, like this:

```
String qlString = "SELECT access " + 
                    "FROM Access AS access " + 
                   "WHERE :role MEMBER OF access.listRole";

Role role = new Role();
role.setId(1L);

List accesses = session.createQuery(qlString).setParameter("role", role).list();
```

Hibernate generates the following SQL query for me (I simplified a bit your entities by removing some attributes):

```
select
    access0_.id as id127_,
    access0_.libelle as libelle127_,
    access0_.name as name127_ 
from
    Access access0_ 
where
    ? in (
        select
            role2_.id 
        from
            Access_ROLES listrole1_,
            ROLES role2_ 
        where
            access0_.id=listrole1_.Access_id 
            and listrole1_.listRole_id=role2_.id
    )
```

Everything seems correct (tested with Hibernate Core 3.3.0.SP1, Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA, Hibernate EM 3.4.0.GA)

What version of Hibernate (Core, Annotations, EntityManager) are you using exactly? What error do you get exactly? Can you show how you invoke the query?

Comment: Thanks a lot,

When I change my query by yours, it works.

(also, I see, my link @ManyToMany between my two class it's not write in the right way. Maybe the problem came from here)

Comment: @Stan: You're welcome. But note that I provided the generated SQL in my answer but I used the JPQL query *you* provided.

Comment: Yes, I know ;-)
The problem has resolved when I modified the links @ManyToMany between my 2 class, like I has explained in my answer.
Thanks.